# Is it possible to delete multiple files at a time from hdfs using hadoop filesystem API?

Tags: java, hadoop, filesystems, delete-file

hadoop shell has the command `hadoop fs -rm /dir/*`. But I don't find a similar one from API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To delete the files in a directory without deleting the directory itself or deleting files from any sub-directories (i.e. what `hadoop fs -rm /dir/*` does) you can use:

```
FileSystem fs = dir.getFileSystem(getConf());
RemoteIterator<LocatedFileStatus> it = fs.listFiles(dir, false);
while (it.hasNext()) {
    fs.delete(it.next().getPath(), false);
}
```

Comment: iterating would result in number of rpm calls right? isnt that taxing the memory?

Comment: It's insignificant in the grand scheme of things - it's effectively what `hadoop fs -rm /dir/*` is doing anyway due to that wildcard. Don't get too caught up in optimization prematurely, this is hardly taxing at all.

Comment: hmm yeah thanks! and by the way executing the hadoop shell command from java would be a bad alternative? will not server the purpose of optimization right?

Comment: You shouldn't really call shell commands from code if you can help it, many potential pitfalls and it's usually considered bad practice. Generally whenever there is an API available, you should opt for that over calling command line functions directly. (That said, I have once had to resort to use a command line call for `distcp` but that was a compatibility issue with the API)

Comment: well bound by limitations in functionality provided by the API.yeah will resort to a recursive delete then.

Comment: ...Why? You dont have to go recursive, I showed you exactly how to achieve what you were after!

Comment: I think/hope he meant he will resort to an iterative delete.

Comment: If this helped can you please mark it as the answer to close off the question?